# Input current of linear regulators

Tags: current, voltage-regulator

I have a basic question about the linear regulators (eg.MC7912CT).
If the output current of the regulator is 1A, what would be the input current? Is it still 1A or less?

Answer (score 2):

The 7812 is a linear voltage regulator and this usually means that the input current is largely determined by the output current. Input current will be a few mA higher due to the chip using current internally to power its circuits, 4mA from memory.

So if the output current is 1.000A the input current might be 1.004A.

A switching regulator is more efficient at delivering power and, for a buck regulator, the input current is usually less than the output current.

Answer (score 1):

In case a picture helps you understand, here is a simplified schematic for a linear regulator. Notice that the only path for current to the output is directly from the input through the series transistor.  The input current will be a bit higher than the output current -- the difference being the current drawn by the internal sense/drive circuitry.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCyMhA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even though the input current is only slightly higher than the output current, the input *power* is significantly higher.  The power dissipated in the pass transistor of the linear regulator is equal to \$I\cdot(V_{in} - V_{out})\$.

Comment: Thank you, I am using 7912CT to convert -24V to -12V. I am worried about the input current is b/c my power supply (-24V) can only provide 1.2A current, and if the input is a lot higher than 1A, I may reach the limit and that's why I worried about. And thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it still 1A or less?

The output current cannot be more than the input current.

To be sure, your question appears focused on *series* linear regulator ICs.

In this case, the input current consists of the *sum* of the output current and the relatively small current required for the active control circuitry to operate.  So, the input current is generally only slightly larger than the output current.

However, and for completeness, there are *shunt* linear regulator ICs such as the [TL431A](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/TL/TL431A.pdf) where the input current can be considerably and perhaps much larger than the output current.  This is due to the fact that regulator works by *shunting* input current around the load.

Comment: You meant to say the output current cannot be *more* than the input current.